# How can I create a race circuit using Cubic Spline?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

My problem is im using Cubic Spline but i get this error trying to graph a race circuit

raise ValueError("`x` must be strictly increasing sequence.")
ValueError: `x` must be strictly increasing sequence.

So one of my questions is. How i do it without using increasing sequence?

I expected to create my race circuit only using cubic spline but i see i cant do it with only 2 arrays of coordinates(x,y). Some proposals?

Comment: Can't you reorder the points so that the `x` values are ordered?

Comment: Even if i do that i dont get what i want because i cant get an interpolation for closing the curves and get a circuit like this.  https://www.racefans.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/07-Nurburgring-on-white-01.jpg

Comment: The scipy cubic spline code is not intended for your kind of curve.  Try to understand its docs and examples (including the circle) first.

Comment: can you tell me about some interpolation that can help me doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cubic spline method requires the independent coordinates of the samples to be sorted. One option would be to parameterize `x` and `y` as a function of, say, `t`, such that `t` is strictly increasing. (Think of `t` being time parameterizing an arbitrary smooth curve in 2 or 3D). Just make a new array `t = sorted array of the size of x that covers the range [0, 1]`, and get two interpolants, one for `t, x` and one for `t, y`.

If you're up to the challenge, take a look at the cubic version of Bezier curves for more inspiration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Comment: As you instructed, I sorted, but it did not produce any results for me because I am unable to get those points close in a circuit race. Heres the image i must represent on a graph. https://www.racefans.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/07-Nurburgring-on-white-01.jpg

Comment: Assuming that the 2-d curve in your figure is represented by `x` and `y` points, you don't need to sort `x` and `y`. All you need is to create a new paramter, `t`, which according to my main response must be sorted, and interpolate `t,x` and `t,y`.

Comment: It works, thank you!