# interpolate with scipy without a strictly increasing sequence

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to do exactly as in this question, but I encounter that the sequence must be strictly increasing, I admit that this question [was answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77334278/how-can-i-create-a-race-circuit-using-cubic-spline), but I really could not implement it correctly.

Comment: Please share an example and what you've tried.